# MASM struct in data section vs struct in the stack

Tags: assembly, winapi, struct, x86-64, masm

I have to call WinApi SHFileOperationW function, but before this I need to fill this struct

```
typedef struct _SHFILEOPSTRUCTW {
HWND         hwnd;
UINT         wFunc;
PCZZWSTR     pFrom;
PCZZWSTR     pTo;
FILEOP_FLAGS fFlags;
BOOL         fAnyOperationsAborted;
LPVOID       hNameMappings;
PCWSTR       lpszProgressTitle;
} SHFILEOPSTRUCTW, *LPSHFILEOPSTRUCTW;
```

In MASM I defined this like that:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT struct 
    hwnd                  dq ?
    wFunc                 dd ?
    pFrom                 dq ?
    pTo                   dq ?
    fFlags                dw ?
    fAnyOperationsAborted dd ?
    hNameMappings         dq ?
    lpszProgressTitle     dq ?
SHFILEOPSTRUCT ends
```

In .data section I init my struct:

```
fos SHFILEOPSTRUCT <?>
```

So when I filling my struct with mov operations and load the address in rcx(1 arg of function) it cause error, but if I push struct fields in the stack and pass to function RSP its work just fine. Why so? Need I fill all the fields even if it 0?
(does not work ↓)

```
mov [fos.hwnd], 0                       ; hWnd
mov [fos.wFunc], FO_DELETE              ; Delete 
mov rax, offset filename
mov [fos.pFrom], rax                    ; Filename
mov [fos.fFlags], FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT                           
lea rcx, fos
```

vs (it's work ↓)

```
push 0
push 0
push 0
push FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT
push 0
pushaddr filename
push FO_DELETE 
push 0
mov rcx, rsp
```

And then ofc I allocate some space in the stack and call the func:

```
sub rsp, 28h 
call SHFileOperationW
```

Comment: Are you sure `mov [fos.hwnd], 0` will generate a `MOV m64, imm32` and not a `MOV m32, imm32`? I don't use MASM. The structure should already be zero-filled.

Comment: The compiler probably adds padding between the struct members to ensure they are aligned, unless it is somehow defined as "packed".  Does MASM do the same?  If not then you would have to add dummy fields in between as needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge yea, I think so. Because when I wrote this code in C,  there are some extra 6 bytes in sizeof() of this structure

Comment: you forget about ALIGN. in x64 for instance pFrom must be aligned on 8 bytes. so 4 bytes between wFunc and pFrom. and 2 bytes bettwen fFlags  and fAnyOperationsAborted . here is 6 bytes = 4 + 2

Comment: SHFILEOPSTRUCT struct **8** must be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [*The C/C++ headers in the Windows SDK assume the platform's default
> alignment is used.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=msvc-170)

this controlled by [/Zp (Struct Member Alignment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=msvc-170) option in both msvc and [ML/ML64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ml-and-ml64-command-line-reference?view=msvc-170) ( The alignment can be 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16)

look also [How align works with data packing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=msvc-170#vclrfhowalignworkswithdatapacking)

difference betweem MSVC and ML64: MSVC use ***/Zp16*** as default for *x64* and *ARM64* but ML64 not.

so you need or direct set /Zp16 in ML64 command line (the best) or direct set aligment in [`STRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/struct-masm?view=msvc-170) declaration:

like `SHFILEOPSTRUCTW struct 16`

---

also declare variable In .data section - mean use global variable and bad solution. this must be local variable, so in stack. code can look like

```
.code

SHFILEOPSTRUCTW struct 16
    hwnd                  dq ?
    wFunc                 dd ?
    pFrom                 dq ?
    pTo                   dq ?
    fFlags                dw ?
    fAnyOperationsAborted dd ?
    hNameMappings         dq ?
    lpszProgressTitle     dq ?
SHFILEOPSTRUCTW ends

FO_DELETE           EQU 03h

FOF_NOCONFIRMATION  EQU 10h
FOF_ALLOWUNDO       EQU 40h
FOF_SILENT          EQU 04h

EXTERN __imp_SHFileOperationW:QWORD

VarSize EQU ((SIZEOF SHFILEOPSTRUCTW + 15) and not 15)
fos EQU [rsp + 20h]


er_ff proc

    sub rsp, 28h + VarSize
    xor eax,eax
    mov fos[SHFILEOPSTRUCTW.hwnd],rax
    mov fos[SHFILEOPSTRUCTW.wFunc],FO_DELETE
    mov fos[SHFILEOPSTRUCTW.pFrom],rcx
    mov fos[SHFILEOPSTRUCTW.pTo],rax
    mov fos[SHFILEOPSTRUCTW.fFlags],FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT
    lea rcx,fos
    call __imp_SHFileOperationW
    add rsp, 28h + VarSize 
    ret
er_ff endp

end
```

so use `SHFILEOPSTRUCTW struct 16` ot better *ml64 /c /Cp **/Zp16*** *"$(InputFileName)"*

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now! But can you please explain calculation of struct size: 
` VarSize EQU ((SIZEOF SHFILEOPSTRUCTW + 15) and not 15) ` Why 15?

Comment: @mantissa - `RSP` before api call must be aligned to 16 bytes and must be `0x20` space. at `er_ff ` begin `RSP == 16*n+8`. so `RSP - 0x28` aligned on 16. space for vars - `VarSize` from one side must be >= `sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT)` and from another size must be `VarSize == 16*m`. so i set it to `(sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT) + 15) & ~15` - this is multiple to 16 bytes ( due to `& ~15` ) and >= than `sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT)`. if use for instanse `(sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT) + 14) & ~15` and `sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT) == 16*k+1`  we got `16*k`. so for align `x` up to 16 need use `(x+15)&~15`